Remove newline from input
Is there a way to remove a single newline character from an input? Something like this
\edef\test{\removenl{  Hello World %
}}

% \test should have `  Hello World `

Context: Consider a file.txt that has the content
This
Test

and consider the MWE
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newread\myfile%
\openin\myfile=file.txt%
\readline\myfile to \thisline%
=\thisline=%
\closein\myfile%
\end{document}

Here \thisline will have the value This\n. I want to remove that single newline character, but keep any whitespace preceding the newline. Is there an easy way to do this?
I can of course trim the string by removing all whitespace including \n, which is not exactly what I want, but it is close.

set \endlinechar=-1 before reading the line

Yep, this resolves my issue. Thanks!

Set \endlinechar=-1 before reading the line (and set it back again afterwards, or use a group)
